# My Cloudflare firewall rule are blocking request from Github. I need bypass a custom URL

Tags: github, cloudflare

I have a Cloudflare Firewall Rule that Blocks ASN from different companies (Amazon, Microsoft etc) to prevent attacks from VPS.

```
(ip.geoip.asnum eq 14618) or (ip.geoip.asnum eq 8075) or (ip.geoip.asnum eq 16276) or (ip.geoip.asnum eq 16509) or (ip.geoip.asnum eq 14061) or (ip.geoip.asnum eq 62567) or (ip.geoip.asnum eq 51167) or (ip.geoip.asnum eq 56617) or (ip.geoip.asnum eq 6188) or (ip.geoip.asnum eq 40819)
```

The problem is that when I run an Actions on my Github repository, Cloudflare is denying it access to my API URL (Due to the rule I already said, since Github uses Microsoft services).
And I need to get a **HTTP 200** code in response from my API URL, but since it is blocking the request, **I only get a HTTP 403 code.** *(Which cloudflare shows as access denied, error 1020)*

I tried to create another Firewall rule to bypass specific URLs of my site, example: https://example.com?api=secretID

```
(http.request.full_uri eq "https://example.com?api=secretID1" and http.request.full_uri eq "https://example.com?api=secretID2" and http.request.full_uri eq "https://example.com?api=secretID3" and http.request.full_uri eq "https://example.com?api=secretID4")
```

But it doesn't work and the requests are still blocked by the first rule, what can I do?

**I don't want to disable the main rule because it puts my site at risk.**

As you can see I have more than 900 attacks per day.
[image: attacks]

## EDIT:

My github action makes 3 GET request per link. And I have 4 Links (1 main domain and other 3 subdomains registered as CNAME:

```
https://example.com/en.php?datazo=secretID
https://sub1.example.com/en.php?datazo=secretID1
https://sub2.example.com/en.php?datazo=secretID2
https://sub3.example.com/en.php?datazo=secretID3
```

**And this is the log from Cloudflare:**

[image: params]

**Inside log: (I used the `https://example.com/en.php?datazo=secretID` example)**

[image: param2]

**RULE "BYPASSING":**

[image]

Comment: In general, ASN blocking is only really useful when you're dealing with a rogue AS from which nothing but abuse comes, or you're trying to narrow an abuse block that has other criteria.  It's not a good general-purpose approach and it definitely shouldn't be used as a form of access control (in part because it can in some cases be subject to spoofing or hijacking).

Comment: @bk2204 I understand, I blocked them because I realized that I suffered attacks trying to search for .env files, or in general trying to steal my site and access it XD, then except for google, I did not see important if I blocked the rest of ASN. Any suggestions to prevent it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a few days and responses from cloudflare support, my solution was this:
Change to "Allow" my "bypassing" rule, since requests that match my filter, will not trigger the rest of firewall rules.

The problem is that "Bypass" was limited exclusively to block what was seen in the screenshot. But it allowed the rest of the rules (including the one blocking ASNs) to be executed.

[image: solution]

Answer (score 1):

Your rule says

```
(http.request.full_uri eq "https://example.com?api=secretID1" and http.request.full_uri eq "https://example.com?api=secretID2" and http.request.full_uri eq "https://example.com?api=secretID3" and http.request.full_uri eq "https://example.com?api=secretID4")
```

This would never be true as your URL can never be equal to more than 1 value at any given time.
Maybe change the `and` to `or`

or instead of `eq` use `contains` or even better
`http.request.uri.query eq`  or
`http.request.uri.query contains`

Comment: Sorry bro, before try I need to ask you what´s the case if are subdomains? All the subdomains are on the same cloudflare domain as CNAME. I cant use http.request.uri.query on the subdomains? Each domain with unique secretID

Comment: `http.request.uri.query` only looks at query params. It does not care about subdomains.
You could have multiple `or` on `http.request.uri.query contains` and add all the subdomain secret values.

Comment: MAN, THANK YOU SO MUCHHHHHHHHHH. Its working. I'll only change the "and" to "or" and the rest of values are the same.

Comment: Bro. i have a problem. The first time when Github request, cloudflare bypass the request, but seconds later the other rule block the request. How i prevent this?[Example on imgur](https://i.imgur.com/9HTyDp9.png)

Comment: Since you only changed `and` to `or`, it might still be just filtering exact query params. For the next requests, you might have more or different query params. Can you post the full_uri for all the requests, both bypassed and blocked?

Comment: Done bro. I modified my question and added full details. Please check :(

Comment: Is bypass rule on top (it has to be 1st rule). The block rule should be below it.
Also, the full_uri includes https only. Is the bot hitting you with HTTP or https?

Comment: Yes, the bypass rule is on top, and yes, the request from the bot are with HTTPS

Comment: From the screenshot, the rule seems to be deactivated. Other than that, unless actually looking at the dashboard, I'm clueless.

Comment: Uh, no. In the screenshot it looks off but it is active right now. No worries, thank you very much for your help. I'll keep looking for how to solve it and if not, I'll ask another question with all the details I can give. Thanks again<3

Comment: @YaelMassieu you're welcome. Do post a note here if you manage to figure out the problem.